# Unable to create solr core

Tags: java, solr

I have a solr 5.2.1 instance and I want to create a new core named production.
I had several issues with access rights which got solved, but the following exception is totally unclear to me. Help is appreciated.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'production': Unable to create core [production] Caused by: solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:661)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:193)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:431)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [production]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:651)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:611)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:628)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:815)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:637)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:491)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:422)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:566)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.createPlugin(PluginBag.java:122)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.init(PluginBag.java:217)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:768)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:793)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:475)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler` class is missing in the path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that you are using an old version of `solrconfig.xml`. Class [JsonUpdateRequestHandler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/JsonUpdateRequestHandler.html) was deprecated in latest Solr 4.x versions and was removed from Solr 5.x. You should use [UpdateRequestHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/UpdateRequestHandler.html) instead of it and  update your `solrconfig.xml` according to your Solr version.